# How can a company or a person reserve an orbit for a satellite?

Tags: spacex, artificial-satellite

How can a company reserve an orbit for a communication satellite? 
And are there any companies which provide an orbit leasing service?

Comment: Related: [1](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/4876/how-is-space-assigned-for-satellites-that-follow-intersecting-orbits), [2](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/5943/who-what-is-the-international-authority-to-assign-refuse-orbit-to-a-satellite-sp), [3](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/19072/for-constellations-of-circular-leo-satellites-are-there-allocations-of-availabl)

Comment: @AAR it looks like there are several questions that are similar if not identical to yours, and most if not all have answers. Is there something different you'd like to ask, or can you find what you are looking for in those answers?